# How to get the signed complement of a number?

Tags: c, binary, twos-complement

I want to find the signed value of a number in C. So if I have a number let's say 10, in binary (in 8 bits) it would be 0000 0110. How do I get the signed number in two's complement 1111 1110, which is -2. Using simple bitwise operations, shifts, masks, how do I do this conversion? I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: I'm not sure what is "signed complement", can you give more examples of input -> expected output?

Comment: Not clear what is asked.

Comment: The additive complement of a number is zero minus the number.  The 2's complement of 0000 0110 would be 1111 1010.

Comment: Do you know how this conversion works on a mathematical level? If not, this does not seem to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

If we already have the binary representation of a positive number `n`, then the bitwise representation of `-n` is `~n+1`, in other words, `1` plus the bitwise negation of the positive number.

Comment: ~n+1 for 0000 0110 will give 1111 1001+1 = 1111 1010, not 1111 1110 as OP wants

Comment: That's not what he wants. The binary representation was 10, and the second was -2. They were not related in the question.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

> I want to find the signed value of a number in C. So if I have a number let's say 10, in binary (in 8 bits) it would be 0000 0110. How do I get the signed number in two's complement 1111 1110, which is -2.

You're confused.  The 8-bit two's complement of 0000 0110 is 1111 1010 (-10 if interpreted as signed, or 6 if interpreted as unsigned).  The whole point is that a bit pattern and its (unsigned) n-bit two's complement add up to 2^n.

> Using simple bitwise operations, shifts, masks, how do I do this conversion? I've been stuck on this for hours.

Here:

```
unsigned char x = 0x0a;
unsigned char twos_complement = (~x) + 1;
```

Comment: Umm... for completeness: binary 00000110 is decimal 6, and 11111010 is decimal -6 if treated as an 8-bit 2's complement number.